# Lightweight Maths library for OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix

greetings all,

I am looking for lightweight (few files or only header file) Maths library for OpenGL(C++) to do Matrix operations (matrix vector multiplication , calculate inverse matrix).

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 5):

[GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/) is header only templated C++ OpenGL matrix library that uses syntax similar to GLSL.

Answer (score 1):

If you google around, you'll find lots of such libraries.  However, any linear algebra library is going to include a LOT more than just simply multiplying and inverting matrices.

If:

1. you're sure you need ONLY this functionality
2. having more would unacceptably alter the performance/size of your application (would only apply if you're developing for some tiny embedded device)

then you'd be better off writing your own (very carefully, with good unit tests).  Otherwise, just use something like Boost, LAPACK or Armadillo.